# Connect all modules in scheme by massive of wires. Verilog

Tags: module, verilog

I have some modules in my scheme and I want to connect it by massive of wires. How it look in my mind:

When come changes of variable some_trigger in top level module, in this moment top level module send signal by `input_output_wire` in module `a1`-> module `a1` make some stuff -> module `a1` send too module `a2` by the `massive_input_output_wire[0]` -> module `a2` make some stuff -> `a2` send by next wire in the massive `massive_input_output_wire[1]` to module `a3` -> `a3` make some stuff -> send to `a4` by `massive_input_output_wire[2]` and so on...

```
module a(
input_output_wire;
);
input input_output_wire;
output input_output_wire;
always @(posedge input_output_wire)
begin
     if(input_output_wire) begin
         ....
             make some stuff
         ....
     end
end
end module


`include "a.v"
module top_level(
clk,
rst,
some_trigger
);
input clk, rst, some_trigger;
parameter NUM_OF_MODULES_A = 5;

wire massive_input_output_wire[0:NUM_OF_MODULES_A];

a a1(.input_output_wire(massive_input_output_wire[0]));
a an(.input_output_wire(massive_input_output_wire[NUM_OF_MODULES_A-1]));
genvar i;
genarate
        for(i=1;i<NUM_OF_MODULES_A-2; i = i + 1)
        begin : modules_a
            a modules_a(
            .(input_output_wire(massive_input_output_wire[i]))
            );
        end
endgenerate


always @(posedge some_trigger)
begin
     if(some_trigger) 
         massive_input_output_wire[0] = 1;
end
endmodule
```

Comment: Sorry: I don't understand what you are asking. Please can you add more explanation?

Comment: Wires are not like variables in programing languages. They do not chain assignments with last one wins. The drive concurrently which often results in Xs. You should not use `assign` or `force` statements to assign a wire within an always block (I'm guessing that is what you are currently doing).

Comment: @MatthewTaylor ok, I want to connect all my modules(`a1`,`a2`,....`an`) in this logic : output wire from `a1`(`massive_input_output_wire[0]`) must go to input of `a2`. Output wire from a2(`massive_input_output_wire[1]`) must go to input of a3 .. output wire from `a[n-1]`(`massive_input_output_wire[n]`) must go to input `a[n]`. The question is how correctly write the code for generate modules (`modules_a`) and for modules that I wrote without generate `a1` and `an`

Comment: @Greg thanks you, I understand my mistake, but my problem now is not in this.

Comment: Module `a` should have at least two ports: an input and an output. `a inst_a( .output_wire(massive_input_output_wire[i]), .input_wire(massive_input_output_wire[i-1]) );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said in your explanation, each module taking one signal and making some stuff and giving another signal to next module to make some another stuff.

To this your module should contain two ports
Like...

```
module a (input_wire,output_wire);
input input_wire;
output reg out_wire;
always
begin
Make some stuff
End 
Endmodule
```

Next in top module you instantiate like below

```
Module top(input_wire,output_wire,another );

Input input_wire ;
Output output_wire [0:3]

Make some stuff
 a a1(input_wire [0],output_wire [0]);
 a a2 (output_wire [0],output_wire [1]);
 a a3 (output_wire [1],output_wire [2]);
 Intantiations

 Endmodule
```

This may help you, if I understand your explanation correctly